# Non-constant treatment periods for A/B test samples

Tags: anova, survival, data-preprocessing, ab-test

I have 4 A/B testing samples with 4 treatment groups and their 4 respective control groups (n=10000~), with known (but not distinct) treatment periods. The issue is that the treatment periods overlap frequently and if I were to remove all user_id where these overlaps occur it would considerably decrease the total number per sample. I don't know how this happened. I also do not know how the treatments were assigned.

I am considering cleaning the samples such that I only include the events from a user_id that are in-between the treatment start date and their proceeding treatment event (if there is an overlap) OR their treatment end-date -- however, I am unsure know how to process the fact that purchases occurring very close to OR on the interval bound may not be related to the treatment event, something which would be more prominent with short intervals. Given that this would result in very inconsistent treatment duration intervals across samples, is this appropriate?

I intend to use survival analysis to consider the time to a purchase event post item view so I can consider how cleaning the data through modifying treatment period length may influence the overall result. Then ANOVA to analyse treatment efficacy between samples. The context of the data is e-commerce, specifically individuals' consumer purchases rather than bulk purchases from a private coorporation. (methods undecided and suggestions are welcomed!)

Comment: So just so I understand, the problem is that your users are exposed to multiple treatments, and you're asking how best to deal with that multiple exposure?

Comment: @DemetriPananos yeah, that sounds about right

Comment: Are purchases very rare, like cars or houses, or frequent? Is the change transitory, like an app upgrade, where each one overrides the previous, or do they stack? Are these treatments related in some way?

Comment: @dimitriy 1) most of the purchases could be frequent, with exception of the things that it wouldn't make much sense to buy multiple of in a short period (like a specific CD),  typical consumer items; stationary, clothing, electronics, etc. 2) The changes are stacked, until the end of the treatment period. 3) yeah, so they are all e-mail campaign based with the tracking pipeline *email referrel* > *item view* > *subsequent item purchase*

Answer (score 3):

There is no "right" approach here so I will give you a couple of options.

- **Remove multiply exposed users** This is the typical approach in AB testing.  However, this is usually done when there are only a handful of multiply exposed users. Too many multiply exposed users may mean that the experiment is underpowered, making the cure worse than the disease.  Additionally, removing these users may create a bias since you may be selecting on non-observables.
- **Do Nothing**  It may justifiable to simply assign each user to the first group they entered and continue as normal.  This depends mostly on the context of the active treatments and the likelihood of interaction effects.  In my own experience, interaction effects are small compared to main effects, especially in CRO type experiments.
- **Model The Interaction** This might be difficult because you have to consider the timing of outcomes  relative to exposures.  Frankly, I'm not sure the juice is worth the squeeze here, and any effort that goes into trying to model your way out of the problem would be better spent with your engineers finding out why this happened and preventing it from happening again.

Comment: solid advice, thank you! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

I would aggregate your data so it looks like this:

```
user_id time_in_exp ft1 ft2 ft3 ft4 fc1 fc2 fc3 fc4 revenue transactions
1       28           1  .75  .5   0   0   0   0   1    100     2
```

Here, user 1 was observed for 28 days and was randomized into T1 on day 1, so the fraction of time in T1 is 100% or 1. He was then randomized into T2 on day 8, T4 on day 15, and was in control for T4. He spent $100 over two transactions. Since you are doing e-mail marketing, we don't need to worry that someone could only be randomized into fewer than four experiments.

Fit a Poisson model of transactions or revenue to this data using time in_exp as the offset, the f1-f4, c1-c4, and no constant. You must drop one of the $c_k$ terms to avoid collinearity.

The expected value is $$E[ y \vert time, f_1, ..., c_1,...]=\exp \left( \ln(time) + \beta_1 \cdot f_1 +\beta_2 \cdot f_2 + \beta_3 \cdot f_3 + \beta_4 \cdot f_4 + \gamma_1 \cdot c_1 +... \right)$$

You can then calculate the multiplicative effect on transactions/revenue from going to 100% in T1 instead of 100% in C1 as $\exp(\beta_1)$. Ideally, this is considerably greater than one. You can also do more complicated additive marginal effects that would let you detect interactions to some extent, even if you don't model them explicitly.

Finally, I would use heteroskedastic errors, especially for revenue. This is called quasi-Poisson MLE.

Comment: This is a really great suggestion! Thank you very much, I will try this out!